# How to print additional string on every other line's contents in bash?

Tags: unix, awk

I'm using `awk '{printf FILENAME ": "} NR%2==0' "$file"`, but it's printing the filename for each line. The desired behavior is for it to only print the filename next to even numbered lines.

Current output:

```
file1: file1: line2
file1: file1: line4
file1:
```

Desired output:

```
file1: line2
file1: line4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using printf(), so the right syntax is

```
$ cat file1.txt
line1
line2
line3
line4

$  awk ' NR%2==0 {printf("%s %s\n", FILENAME ": ", $0) } '  file1.txt
file1.txt:  line2
file1.txt:  line4

$
```

When you use

```
$ awk '{printf FILENAME ": "} NR%2==0'  file1.txt
file1.txt: file1.txt: line2
file1.txt: file1.txt: line4

$
```

The printf prints `file1.txt:` and then for every even line number NR%2==0 evaluates to true, so it prints again `file1.txt: line2`

To know, what is happening just remove the NR%2==0,

```
$ awk '{printf FILENAME ": "} '  file1.txt
file1.txt: file1.txt: file1.txt: file1.txt:
$
```

so, printf just prints the filename without new lines. The right usage of printf() is like C syntax - specify format specifier %s for string, %d for Int, etc followed by the variable. 
ex `printf("%d %s\n", NR, $0 )`

```
$ awk ' { printf("%d %s\n", NR, $0 ) }' file1.txt
1 line1
2 line2
3 line3
4 line4

$
```

Note that there is difference between where you place the condition

`awk ' NR%2==0 {printf("%s %s\n", FILENAME ": ", $0) } '  file1.txt`

is different from

`awk '  {printf("%s %s\n", FILENAME ": ", $0) } NR%2==0 '  file1.txt`

Both give different results

The first one checks the condition and then prints - so you get only 2 lines.
The second prints all lines by default and when "NR%2==0" is true, the $0 is printed again - you get 6 lines ( 4 original + 2 for the true condition )

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR%2==0{print FILENAME": " $0}'  Input_file
```

OR as per OP's try in case you are passing a variable in pace of Input_file

```
awk 'FNR%2==0{print FILENAME": " $0}' "$file"
```

To avoid too many open files error try following once.

```
awk 'prev!=FILENAME{close(prev)} FNR%2==0{print FILENAME": " $0} FNR==1{prev=FILENAME}' "$file"
```